# Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists

Tags: sql-server-2005, linked-server

I've got a Linked Server in my SQL Express install that is using SQL Server Authentication.

I've created a SQL Server login-mapping and it's using Impersonate.

I've confirmed that the account exists on both servers but I'm still getting the error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just make certain I understand, in the linked server security you have specified a local login that is a SQL login that you wish to impersonate as the remote user?

Comment: Yes, and its credentials match on both servers.

Comment: Could this be Kerberos related as in the servers (& service accounts) involved needing to be configured for Kerberos delegation?

Comment: Did you provide your connection string as "**Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;**"?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you attempting to login from ?

An application on a 3rd server, or an SSMS on the same (database) server, or a 3rd server ?

In the first and last case, you are going to run into the dreaded double-hop issue.

It is not Kerberos-related, since you say you're using SQL server authentication, which does not use AD in any way.